# Android Custom ListView - How to prevent auto Refresh(update) of ListView Adapter on Scrolling

Tags: android, listview

I want to stop listview automatic update(refresh) thing on LIstView scrolling..

OR

How can i assign a new adapter to the same ListView on scrolling???

Please help!!

Comment: anyone???? with great expertise in android dev..

Comment: its like whenever i scroll my custom listview, it redraws itself while assigning the intial Adapter object. and this way it resets the listview items. i dont want this thing to happen. 1- listview should not update(re-draw) itself 2- i may be able to assign new adapter to listview(this can be done using OnscrollListener , i tried that as well but no help)

Comment: What are you trying to do? I mean, what is your scenario for which you need this?

Comment: in my case i am changing numbers(TextView) by clicking +,- buttons.but whenever i try to scroll the listview, it resets the numbering.

Answer (score 0):

try to set number as a Tag view.setTag(number) and get it in OnItemClickListener :

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {         
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view,
                            int position, long arg3) {
        if (position > 0 && position < mProducts.alternatives.size() + 1){
        int number = (Integer)view.getTag();
        }
    }
});
```